# Newtonsoft.Json DeserializedObject wrong property values

Tags: json.net

using the example found here. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

deserializedProduct doesn't end up with the correct values. Can somebody point out what I'm missing please?

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Product product = new Product();

            product.Name = "Apple";
            product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
            product.Price = 3.99M;
            product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

            string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
            //{
            //  "Name": "Apple",
            //  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
            //  "Price": 3.99,
            //  "Sizes": [
            //    "Small",
            //    "Medium",
            //    "Large"
            //  ]
            //}

            Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
        }
    }

    class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; internal set; }
        public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; internal set; }
        public decimal Price { get; internal set; }
        public string[] Sizes { get; internal set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properties need public getters and setters when deserializing in order to be able to set the values

```
class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string[] Sizes { get; set; }
}
```